# How to find an element which doesn't have proper attribute

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath, katalon

- I need to click on an element which is inside the div tag. I tried using the xpath which when used detects the element both in the console and in the Katalon ide.
- But when the script is run, it doesn't detect the element as the path given doesn't exactly point to the cancel icon I need to click.
- I have attached a screenshot highlighting the element and its attribute. [image]

Comment: can't you target by the `close` class?

Comment: @Adelin It doesn't catch the close icon even if I give that as the attribute. Gave all the types of attributes. Still it can't perform any actions on that icon

Comment: What's the exact code you used, for both the xpath and the `close` class?

Comment: @FindBy(css = "div.close")
    WebElement CloseButton; 


        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(CloseButton));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(CloseButton).build().perform();
       
        CloseButton.click();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@class='prompt']/..")
     WebElement choiceHeader;
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(choiceHeader));
     Integer parentWidth = choiceHeader.getSize().width;
     Actions ac = new Actions(driver);
    ac.moveToElement(choiceHeader, parentWidth-13, 13).click().build().perform();
```

- This does find the element and then scroll to the position and click on the element which was highlighted in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@FindBy(css = "#demo_page1 .close")
WebElement CloseButton;
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(CloseButton));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
Thread.sleep(3000);
action.moveToElement(CloseButton).build().perform();
CloseButton.click();
```

And also take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673465/in-selenium-webdriver-expectedcondition-elementtobeclickable-is-not-waiting-unt).

Comment: The mentioned answer doesn't work. It gives the same error as previous. I found a solution which does work without any issues.